# Android application transparency and window sizing at root level

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to create an application with a transparent background
on the root task such that you can see the task running beneath it
when it is part of a separate stack? Alternatively, is it possible to
run an application so the window of the root task is only a portion of
the screen instead of the whole screen?

I understand how the transparency and window sizing is done with
activities that are not the root task and this works fine. However,
the root task of an activity seems to always fill the whole screen and
be black even when a transparent theme is applied to the application
object in the manifest file.

ApplicationManifest.xml:

`<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                       android:label="@string/app_name"
                       android:debuggable="true"
                       android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">`

Styles.xml

`<resources>
 <style name="Theme.Transparent">
       <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/
transparent_background</item>
       <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/
Animation.Translucent</item>
       <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
       <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
               <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
 </style>
</resources>`

Colors.xml

`<resources>
  <drawable name="transparent_background">#00000000</drawable>
</resources>`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have your application run with a transparent background.  You don't even need to define your own theme all you need to so is add:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

to the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.  As for having your app only take up part of the screen, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that the error I experienced is when you try to do the same thing in your own style instead of using one of the defaults... http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg33167.html